# When does a push notification channel change?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application where am implementing push notification concept.Here I want to send channel URI to my server at the time my application installation,So in which event I need to get channel URI and in which event I need to send this URI to server.Actually, here I observed that the channel URI is varying only when we uninstall our application and re-installing.Otherwise it will be constant.Can anyone suggest me which events I need to use,here am using HTML5 & WinJS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A new push notification channel URI isn't always created when the channel API is called. The `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync` method will return a cached local copy of the channel URI for a period of time (currently 24 hours).

The [how-to article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465412.aspx) provides guidance about channel management summarized here:

- Whenever the app is run, request a new channel.
- If the new channel URI is different from the old channel URI:

  - Replace the channel URI on the service with the new channel URI.
  - Once your service has the channel, store the new channel URI for future comparisons.